# Several TextViews or Concatenated Strings?

Tags: android, string, performance, textview, code-maintainability

Approach 1: In an android app there is shown a duration TextView (like: "*2* h *45* m") and another TextView with number of Stops (like: "Stops: *15*"). Between them is another TextView (" | ") to separate them.

Approach 2: using only one TextView, a String template and concatenation to put it together.

Consider the data (*2 45* and *15*) comes from backend and the number of stops isn't really logically connected to the duration.

My Question is:

Which approach is more efficient considering performance and code-maintainability?
Is there a better way of doing this or are there any best practices?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple TextViews for this. You have a format and just want to put values in there. I would suggest the following way

```
int h = 2;
int m = 45;
int s = 15;
String format = String.format("%dh %dm | Stops: %d ", h, m, s);
```

Now assign `format` string to your one TextView

Comment: So, it perfomes better?

Comment: Yep, it will and it's more easily maintainable.